# don't know how to get object property from ontology in java with Hermit

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api, protege4, hermit

I'm trying to get an object property from a class, in particular: I'm trying to understand when a class is a part of some other class (the construct used could be seen in the screenshot).

[image]

I've already tried to use the **OWL-api** function `getObjectPropertiesInSignature()` on a `OWLClass` object (the object is "e").

```
//display delle object property
Set<OWLObjectProperty> proprietà = e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature();
System.out.println("Object Property:");
if(proprietà.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("\tQuesta classe non ha object property");
}
else {
    for(OWLObjectProperty prop : proprietà) {
        System.out.println("\t"+ prop);
    }
}
```

The output of the snippet is `Questa classe non ha object property`, so the function returns an empty Set, But In this case, it should return a Set with one object property: **the part-Of object property**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to find out is whether a class is included in the domain of an object property (classes do not 'have' object properties in OWL), or whether the class is a subclass of a restriction. The signature of a class object contains object properties only when a class expression mentions a property, for example a qualified cardinality restriction or an existential restriction, as in your example.

In order to see whether a class has a superclass that uses `partOf`, you can create a class expression representing the right hand side of your subclass axiom and ask for its subclasses.

```
OWLDataFactory df = ...
OWLClassExpression c = df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(partOf, car);
NodeSet subClasses = hermit.getSubClasses(c, false);
```

For classes in the domain of partOf, you have to look for subclasses of the intersection of the domain expressions:

```
OWLClassExpression domain = df.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(ontology.objectPropertyDomainAxioms(partOf));
NodeSet subClassesInDomain = hermit.getSubClasses(domain, false);
```

Comment: Ok, but now I don't know how to instantiate the OWLDataFactory class. I tried to look for tutorials on the web, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Look at the wiki pages on the owlapi github repository.